# Sourdough starter issues

Tags: baking, bread, sourdough, sourdough-starter

I've been trying unsuccessfully to create my sourdough starter. First of all it starts off well, i combine 100g of bread flour with 100g of water (bottled) mix well and leave it in my jar covered with cloth for 24 hours. Next day i always have a bit of action in my jar, so i feed it another 100g both of my water and flour and leave for another 24 hours. So on day 3 my starter has gone crazy doubling or even more in size and shrinking again by the time the 24 hour period is up. Next step is where my starter dies every time, I discard half and add another 100g of flour and 100g of water. After a further 24 hours there are slight bubbles but not much life at all, so i continue the process but never get anywhere close to action i was getting on day 2 and 3. Can anyone tell me why my starter is dying when i do the "discard and feed" process?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It looks like you also asked [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/77908/how-frequently-should-i-feed-my-sourdough-starter) as a different user. You should stick with one account, and not ask the same question multiple times. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) question for how to get your accounts merged.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to keep feeding the starter a few more days before starting the 'discard and feed'. Fermentation is a process that requires a LOT of patience, as everything else in baking.

On the other hand I tried and could successfully make a starter following these instructions. I love The Kitchn and Emma Christensen. Her baking tutorials are among the best.

http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-your-own-sourdough-starter-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-47337

Answer (score 0):

It usually takes 5 to 7 days of feeding twice a day for the yeast and bacteria in the starter to get to the billions needed for baking. I would suggest feeding it every 12 hours, discarding all but 100 grams and using 100 grams of flour and 100 grams of water at each feeding. After five to seven days it should be mature enough to either sit in the fridge til needed (not more than a week between feedings) or feed it once a day out on the counter. Others have said it takes patience, and it does, but it is worth the effort. I would also read everything I could on the subject.